# Trouble to add Apache POI integration in Java project using eclipse dependencies

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm trying to create an Excel spreadsheet and I intend to use the Apache POI library, but it's returning an error. I've already added the JAR files, but the message remains the same. What else could be wrong?

[image]

The message returned is:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems:
Workbook cannot be resolved to a type
XSSFWorkbook cannot be resolved to a type
Sheet cannot be resolved to a type
Row cannot be resolved to a type
Cell cannot be resolved to a type

[image]

Comment: i would suggest looking into and using a dependency management system like maven https://maven.apache.org/

Comment: Works!!!! Tks!!!!

Answer (score 1):

After restarting the project as Maven project, I added the dependencies to the pom.xml file, and the application worked correctly.